# how to write a trigger without nested FOR loop

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, sql, sqlserver

I wrote a trigger but My professor asked me to write it without nested loop and I don't know how to do it.
I want to do is when a contact gets created i need to take field named- 'Description' of contact and update it on a field- Description present on the opportunity records (where stage='closed won')  associated with the contact's Account Id. so the problem is:

```
trigger contactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {

    if (trigger.isInsert && trigger.isbefore){

        

        List<Opportunity> optoUpdate=new List<Opportunity>();

        Set<Id> accId =new Set<Id>();

        for(Contact c:trigger.new){

            accId.add(c.AccountId);

        }

        List <Opportunity> oppToUpdate=new List <Opportunity>();

        oppToUpdate=[select AccountId,Description from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' and AccountId in :accId];

        Map<Id,List <Opportunity>> testmap=new Map<Id,List<Opportunity>>();

        for(Opportunity op:oppToUpdate){

            if (testmap.containsKey(op.AccountId)){

                testMap.get(op.AccountId).add(op);

            }

            else{

                testmap.put(op.AccountId,new list<Opportunity>{op});

            }

        }

        

        for(Contact c:trigger.new){

            if (testmap.containsKey(c.AccountId)){

                for(opportunity op:testmap.get(c.AccountId)){

                    if(op.description ==''){

                    op.description=c.description;

                    }

                    else{

                       op.description=op.description+c.description; 

                    }

                        

                    optoUpdate.add(op);

                    

                }

            }

        }

        

       update optoUpdate;        

    }

}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to avoid doing this is to pre-concatenate the strings so you don't need to loop over the contacts again. At a basic level, that looks like this:

```
trigger contactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    Map<Id, String> descriptions = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(Contact contactRecord: Trigger.new) {
        // If the contact has a description, we'll put it in the map.
        if(contactRecord.Description != null) {
            String description = descriptions.get(contactRecord.AccountId);
            // Avoids "null" being placed in the description.
            if(description == null) {
                description = '';
            }
            // There may be more than one, so we'll concatenate if so.
            description += contactRecord.Description;
            descriptions.put(contactRecord.AccountId, description);
        }
    }
    // Do not query Opportunity with AccountId = null.
    descriptions.remove(null);
    Opportunity[] opportunitiesToUpdate = [SELECT AccountId, Description FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :descriptions.keySet() AND StageName = 'Closed Won'];
    for(Opportunity opportunityRecord: opportunitiesToUpdate) {
        // Avoid null in the resulting description text.
        if(opportunityRecord.Description == null) {
            opportunityRecord.Description = '';
        }
        opportunityRecord.Description += descriptions.get(opportunityRecord.AccountId);
    }
    update opportunitiesToUpdate;
}
```

Please note that this fixes a bug in your code. Text fields retrieved from the database will never be an empty string (`''`), you need to check for null values instead.

Note also how you can update records from the same variable you stored a query from, and some unnecessary logic was removed.

Also, it is generally advisable to only perform updates on related records in an after trigger, not a before trigger. This is because another trigger could modify the contents of a record before you get to read the data, leading to inconsistent results.

Comment: sfdcfox, what is the purpose of _descriptions.remove(null);_ given that you change null values to empty strings before adding them to _descriptions_  ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO I do this because I don't want to query Opportunity records with a null AccountId. This could have also been done in the if statement, it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Of course, Map.remove() removes by key, not by value, my mistake !